# java - Editing child in list of parents

Tags: java, list, arraylist, extends

I've got an abstract class called customer and another classe called payCust that extends this abstract class. There is another client class that initializes a list of customers.`List<Customer> custList = new ArrayList<>();`

the customer class has a constructor as follows:

```
public Customer(String name, String email, String mag) {
        this.CusEmail = email;
        this.CusName = name;
        this.magazine = mag;
    }
```

payCust has the following constructor:

```
public PayCust(String _name, String _email, String _accountType, String _custMag) {
        super(_name, _email, _custMag);
        this.accountType = _accountType;
    }
```

all the variables have public get and set methods. e.g.

```
public void setName(String name) {
            this.CusName = name;
        }
public String getName() {
        return this.CusName;
    }
```

my question is that if the `custList` had a `PayCust` added to it. how can i edit the accountType of a customer from that list?
note: email is unique to every customer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check the instance type of the object within the ArrayList and cast it for usage.

Something like this, for example:

```
for (Customer c : custList){
    if(c instanceof PayCust){
        PayCust pc = (PayCust) c;
        pc.getAccountType();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the better answer if you have multiple subclass of Customer in the list.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to cast it to a `PayCust` (assuming you know for a fact that it's a `PayCust`):

```
PayCust example = (PayCust) custList.get(0);
String accountType = example.getAccountType ();
...
```